# Remove pre-ceding text from DateItem and TimeItem

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a Start and End `DateItem` and `TimeItem`. The `DateRange` control does not provide what I need in SmartGWT and I prefer to have separate controls.

How can I remove the text from the beginning of the control for the `DateItem` and `TimeItem`?

Currently, it shows Date: **__** []

where the *_*_ is the text-entry and the [] is the date picker.

I want to remove the text Date:

I tried setting the title to "" in the DateItem constructor, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. You must use `.setShowTitle(false)` to remove the form item's title.